# How to implement the pull to refresh in CDK virtual scrolled angular application

Tags: angular, smooth-scrolling, pull-to-refresh, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

Currently I am using CDK virtual scroll in the DOM, but when scrolling fast there is glitch happening in the DOM , so I am planning to implement the Pull to refresh method, so how to implement this pull to refresh or any other solution for this glitch issue

Answer (score 1):

ionic supports this behaviour with its `ion-refresher` component

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher#usage-with-virtual-scroll

You could either use this component or look into their repo as to how they implement it

Answer (score 0):

If you see a glitch when scrolling fast with `CdkVirtualScroll`, it usually means that the `itemSize` on your `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` is not correct.

If it's off by a few pixels it won't matter that much if you scroll slowly, but if you scroll quickly then `CdkVirtualScroll` will run into trouble because the difference between `itemHeight` and the actual item height becomes too large for it to calculate correctly which items to show.

Go to your browser dev tools and measure the exact height of your items. The height should be fixed.

Let's assume you measured an item height of `50px`. Then, in your template:

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">
```